# Laravel 4.2 Artisan Console Progress Bar

Tags: symfony, laravel, console, progress-bar, laravel-artisan

I would like to ask if somebody has managed to show a symfony progress bar in the artisan console.

I'm using Windows 7 and the Laravel 4.2 framework.

So far, the code I've been using is below:

```
$progress = $this->getHelper('progress');

$progress->start($this->getOutput(), 5);

$i = 0;

while ($i++ < 5) {

    sleep(1);

    $progress->advance();

}


$progress->finish();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

```
$progress = $this->getHelperSet()->get('progress');

$progress->start($this->getOutput(), 5);

$i = 0;

while ($i++ < 5) {

    sleep(1);

    $progress->advance();

}


$progress->finish();
```

Comment: I found out that to properly output the progressbar, your console should support ANSI.

thanks @matt-mcdonald